# call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url) 28 | http.begin(URL);

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to simulate sending temperature and humidity variables to xampp (localhost) via Post, using the idle arduino, but I'm encountering this error in compilation:
[used board:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JusS.png)

```
C:\Users\dossa\OneDrive\Documentos\Arduino\sketch_aug22a\sketch_aug22a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
C:\Users\dossa\OneDrive\Documentos\Arduino\sketch_aug22a\sketch_aug22a.ino:28:13: error: call to 'HTTPClient::begin' declared with attribute error: obsolete API, use ::begin(WiFiClient, url)
   28 |   http.begin(URL);
      |   ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
```

Here is the function code void loop()

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

HTTPClient http;
WiFiClient client;

String URL = "http://192.168.0.107/dht11_project/test_data.php";

const char* ssid = "NetLine_4674_2.4G";
const char* password = "afonso7070";

int temperature = 50; 
int humidity = 50;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  connectWiFi();
}

void loop() {
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    connectWiFi();
  }

  String postData = "temperature=" + String(temperature) + "&humidity=" + String(humidity); 

  HTTPClient http; 
  http.begin(URL);

  
  int httpCode = http.POST(postData); 
  String payload = http.getString(); 
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


  Serial.print("URL : "); Serial.println(URL); 
  Serial.print("Data: "); Serial.println(postData); 
  Serial.print("httpCode: "); Serial.println(httpCode); 
  Serial.print("payload : "); Serial.println(payload); 
  Serial.println("--------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Please help-me

I already tried to change the board to esp32 dev module, but another error appears: Sketch uses 828549 bytes (63%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes. Global variables use 45008 bytes (13%) of dynamic memory, leaving 282672 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes. Failed uploading: no upload port provided

Comment: the error message tells you the problem and the solution too. and look at the examples.